# XCode Swift autocomplete breaks down after build

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, xcode7

I've got a project that started out two years ago as Obj-C, but recently has had a number of Swift 2.0 additions. Right now the ratio is about 75%/25% in favor of Obj-C, but growing towards Swift.

Common with older projects, right? Here's the problem: ever since XCode 7.3 I can't get code completion to work properly in Swift.

I take these steps:

- Close Xcode
- Terminal -> rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
- Terminal -> rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode

and all is good. But as soon as I do a full build of the XCode project, the problem's back and Swift doesn't code-complete until I remove the derived data again (either manually or through XCode), and re-index all the files.

Objective-C does complete, and the default and manually created macros also still work. It's just the indexing that seems to break.

Please, has anyone heard of this behaviour and know a fix for it? 
It's great Swift training to have to type everything manually, but some of my methods have multiple block-parameters and it becomes a pain to write them out.

If it matters at all, I've been using Swift 2.0 up to 2.2 syntax in the newer classes.

Comment: Does your app build and run? If so, can you reduce the issue to a small demo project? If so, file a bug report with Apple!

Comment: This happens all the time. The dev tools for Swift just suck.

Comment: Do you have a lot of files in a bridging header?

Comment: Lots and lots and lots and lots. And I have found this to be the cause of it as well; I broke down a part of the project which seemed to work fine, but when I hook up the additional 75% of the code, the syntax highlighting disappears. Unfortunately, there are a lot of required dependencies; the only alternative is to rewrite most of the code written back to Objective-C so I can remove a lot of those dependencies. Which is not really an option.

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your deployment target? i find out it it always works on `10.12`:
[image]

Comment: Hey, Base SDK is the newest, but for this project we still support iOS 9.0.